# I have a .SQL file which contains a database dump of a library index which contains 22.5 million books. I need to convert this to an Excel sheet

Tags: mysql

I believe this file is a database dump for the ZLib index (similar to piratebay but for books which got taken down). I am attempting to convert the .SQL file into .XLXS ultimately. I have found the file simply too large for most applications (8GB) to load so I found a dump splitter and used that to break it down into smaller parts. I have near zero knowledge of SQL and only really need to learn enough to get this done.

My ultimate goal would be to have the entire dataset in a spread sheet format such that a user could ctrl + f and type a title or author and find what index they need to pull.

The best path to what I want to do appears to be somehow restoring the database locally on my computer from the database dump, and then exporting from there. This is where I am getting stuck. I have SQL SMSS installed as well as SQL Workbench but Im really starting from near zero and every piece of advice Ive found seems to assume some minimal base knowledge.

I have found a convenient webapp that converts straight from .sql to .xlxs but it only does so in 19mb increments and I have a 8GB file to work with so that would simply be too tedious to do manually. I am familiar with Bash and JS so not adverse to learning more. Maybe it could be possible to write a bash script that automates the uploading of the 19mb files to the webabb? Would appreciate any direction for further reading to learn what I need to do or any straight forward guidance on how to proceed. Thank you all!

Edit: This is the code at the top of the file;

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS,
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE,
SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `books`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `zlibrary_id` int NOT NULL,
  `date_added` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `extension` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `filesize` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `filesize_reported` bigint NOT NULL,
  `md5` char(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `md5_reported` char(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `author` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `publisher` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `language` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `series` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `volume` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `edition` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `year` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pages` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cover_url` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `in_libgen` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pilimi_torrent` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `unavailable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`zlibrary_id`),
  KEY `md5` (`md5`),
  KEY `md5_reported` (`md5_reported`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `books` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `books` DISABLE KEYS */;
```

UPDATE: I followed some guides and got server installed and created a new database using workbench and am now importing the dump file. I used the SHOW PROCESSES; command to check progress because it didnt look like it was doing anything on the import status tab. It shows its processing but it appears its going to take an extremely long time to import the full 8gb dump.

Comment: Excel has a limit of about a million rows per sheet. You won't be able to load this into a single sheet.

Comment: I suggest you just keep it in the database and use a database query tool rather than Excel.

Comment: Yeah I was going to break down the excel sheets into multiple files. The constraint I'm facing is that this needs to be usable locally by a not so savvy person. I wont be able to host the database in perpetuity for them. So having the index saved in a readable format that can be searched would make things easier for the end user its going to.

Comment: There are 22.5 million entries, of which I plan to extract only the english listings. So it should end up around 8 or so pages of a million entries each by my estimate.

Comment: You still can't load that into a single sheet. You'll need to use a SQL tool to filter the data and then export those results to multiple XLS files.

Comment: Is the sql dump in the `.sql` file from mysql? If so you'll likely need to restore it into a mysql server, not an MS Sql Server. What you have in front of you is an unenviable task, even by someone that is skilled. `.sql` files are just not great for anything besides backup, where your usecase is ETL/Migration.

Comment: @Barmar understood thank you. do you have any recommendations for tools to use to accomplish this task?

Comment: You already mentioned it: MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @JNevill is there a way to tell where the file is from? I can open it in VIM and navigate through the file in an unorganized raw format, the top of the file has the instructions for the dividing columns and formatting, would that information be in there?

Comment: If the top of the file has like `CREATE TABLE <sometablename> ( <col1> <coltyp1>, <col2> <coltype2>` type DDL language in it, then it may be possible to discern what RDBMS platform from which that sql dump was generated. Each RDBMS syntax is ever-so-slightly different. Feel free to paste into the question with an edit.

Comment: That is a mysql dump.

Comment: And the table is from INNODB engine storage.  How will you select 'only the english listings'?

Comment: Could you install MySQL Version 8.0.33 on a PC you are in control of?

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have already installed it along with MySQL Shell and Workbench. But I am not sure how much of it works.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, my best bet at accomplishing what I want is to restore this mysql dump to a mysql server and then from there export to multiple xls files?

Comment: How will you SELECT 'only the english listings'?  View profile, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I was hoping once the dataset was restored to a server I could sort by language column and export only english to .csv or .xlsx. I am currently importing the dump file now via workbench.

Comment: Great.  You are making progress. What in the 'language' column will be your WHERE clause?  I will help you get to a 'books-english' only table.  SORTING by language can be avoided.

Comment: @Nirvahnah Please review this URL for how to copy data.  https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-copy-table-data.aspx 
use ctrl+f to search for insert  
to get the area where we will need to enhance for your specific request to NOT copy when language is NOT english.  i.e.  SELECT * from books WHERE language <> "English%";  or something similar.  We will be able to save hours, if we could Skype TALK.

Comment: @WilsonHauck You are unbelievably helpful, thank you so much! Im not at the computer in question at the moment but I will follow up later for skype chat, thanks again!

Comment: @Nirvahnah     Correction to select only English - SELECT * from books WHERE language LIKE "%English%; or something similar for the needed rows in the destination table.